# {position : sticky} in div not work if added a textfield

Tags: css, html, sticky

I have a problem when using `{position : sticky}`,
When I'm scrolling below the top bar, and the sticky will follow.
If I type something in the textfield on the sticky bar (when sticking) browser will jump to the top.

```
<! -- example link  -->
```

https://codepen.io/MoMoWongHK/pen/WOEqKd

Is it a bug of {position : sticky} ?

Comment: `position: sticky` is expiremental and should not be used in production _yet_. It has frequent behaviour changes, so you should not trust it *just yet*.

Comment: Any alternative solution that can replace using position: sticky ?

Comment: There are plugins. Please check out my answer.

Comment: @ItayGanor sure

Answer (score 0):

`position: sticky` is unstable and should not be used in production *just yet*. An alternative solution is to use plugins, such as my favorite [Sticky.js](http://stickyjs.com/).